# Checking value in an array inside one SQL query with WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to know is this practically possible in sql(using php as server-side), where in you have an array of values(numbers), and you try to retrieve data based on values inside that array..

I have a sql table:

```
posts(
    id int(11) primary key,
    posts varchar(140),
    user_id int(11) foreign key
);
```

I write a query now to retrieve 'posts':

```
$query="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=(**Array of select user_id's**)";
```

Is there any sql in-built function to check values inside an array? or should I be using PHP for this?

I am actually trying to implement the twitter model of showing posts of people whom we follow.

Comment: SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3);

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SQL can't parse PHP arrays. Try this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN ({implode(',', $userIDarray)})";
```

Comment: Just be careful that the array values have been sanitized for SQL injection.

Comment: Of course... I for myself would use prepared statements, but that's not the question ;)

Comment: wat sanitary functions needed to sanitise an array?

Comment: in this case only integer values are permitted. So you need to check for integer values in each array element. If you don't generate this array from user inputs (or the values of the arrays do not contain any) you can skip this.

Comment: you forgot an ) after the variable

Answer (score 40):

Yes, this is easily possible. You need to look at [MySQL's IN function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Your query would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

You can build the bit in between the parentheses in PHP using [implode()](http://uk.php.net/implode)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this page : [WHERE ... IN](http://data.agaric.com/mysql-where-1-4-5-syntax). You can use the IN operator to check if a certain value exists within an list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you will have to you use following syntax

```
SELECT 'value'
 IN (array)
```

Comment: stop linking to your website like this.