# How optimize while in while code?

Tags: php, variables, process, foreach, while-loop

My code is :

```
$text = '12-10-4-32-45-name-sara-x-y-86';
$array = explode('-',$text);
foreach($array as $value) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `pid`='$value' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo $row['title'];
        echo '';
    }
    echo '';
}
```

This code work full but if in $text use 150 variable , server down !

How optimize this code for most variable ?!

Thx

Comment: Use an `IN` clause, perhaps? `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE pid IN ($in) ...`. (Do note that the above code is still **vulnerable to SQL injection**. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should switch to MySQLi/PDO and properly escape the  input using prepared statements.)

Comment: Learn about MySQL IN clause

Comment: This question might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270134/checking-value-in-an-array-inside-one-sql-query-with-where-clause

Comment: put all your values in 1 string variable, separated by ",", and put that in your query. 

Use in your query the pid IN (......)

Comment: Thx, But for each variable echo 3 title ! how fixed it ?!

Comment: I use IN but return first record variable !

Comment: do you really need to check if, example: `pid='name'`? or you just want numbers

Comment: No , i need check pid='name' and other values

Comment: Please do not duplicate your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all of them as ids (which includes a string which is weird). Consider this example:

```
$text = '12-10-4-32-45-name-sara-x-y-86';
$text = array_unique(explode('-', $text)); // just in case there are duplicate ids
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `pid` IN("'.implode('", "', $text).'") ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3';

// should be like this
// SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `pid` IN("12", "10", "4", "32", "45", "name", "sara", "x", "y", "86") ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3
// then just continue on your mysql_query
$sql = mysql_query($statement);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    // print your values or whatever it is you need to do
    // echo $row['title'];
}
```

---

> *Note: You don't need to query each value, that would be a total waste of resources. Imagine your text has (as you said) 150 numbers. Try to use the **`IN()`** of mysql so that it just make a single trip of query.*

Comment: Thx, But i use NUMBER AND VARCHAR !

Comment: @user3612383 if you really need them all to be inside the query, i edited the answer

Comment: Thx, But this code return last 3 three query. but i want get last 3 three query for each value of $text

Comment: Well this situation was not specified earlier, and the current answer does not meet that situation. if you really want to query each values of `$text`, then i can suggest using msqli `multi_query` instead, or you could, first each query assign it inside an array, then free the result