# Optimize while and SQL in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, process, foreach, while-loop

My code :

```
$text = '12-name-y-86';
$array = explode('-',$text);
foreach($array as $value) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `pid`='$value' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3");
    echo '***'.$value.'***';
    echo '<br />';    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo $row['title'];
        echo '<br />';
    }
    echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

Print :

***12***

title1

title2

title3

***name***

ti1

ti2

ti3

***y***

tle1

tle2

tle3

***86***

mytitle1

mytitle2

mytitle3

This code work full buy for more values in $text , server has down !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How optimize while in while code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519227/how-optimize-while-in-while-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select all records in just one query, like this:

```
$text = '12-name-y-86';
$array = explode('-', $text);
$array = "'" . implode(',', $array) . "'";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `pid` IN (' . $array . ') ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $row['title'];
    echo '<br />';
}
echo '<br /><br />';
```

Comment: resource(49) of type (mysql result) , but not echo titles !